# Total summary cart, add number of items | Get number of items in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, order-summary

I want to add "Total Items" row to display current amount of items in the cart.

Something like this:
[image: items]

How can I display the `$_cartQty` in this summary section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit `app\design\frontend\THEME\PACKAGE\template\checkout\cart\totals.phtml`, you can use

```
<?php echo $this->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();  
foreach ($items as $item) {  
    echo 'Product Quantity: '.$item->getQty();
}
```

OR

```
echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

OR

```
$count = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
```